# Accuracy_score appears wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('Accuracy: ' + str(int(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))))
```

result:

```
Accuracy: 0
```

and here the variables:

```
>>> y_pred
array([36, 36], dtype=int64)

>>> y_test
0    24
4    36
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

As you can see the `36` is a correct prediction. Why the accuracy isn't `0.50` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the int and it will give 0.5. This is because by putting int you can't return a float like the 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

do not parse it to integer.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('Accuracy: ' + str(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be different data type you are passing in accuracy_score. I think you are passing `y_pred` as numpy array and `y_test` as pandas object. please use `.values` for getting numpy array from pandas dataframe

```
accuracy_score(y_test.values,y_pred)
```

*Note* : According to sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) usage of accuracy_score is like accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)